# Doctrine Make Join

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Users Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="users", options={"collate":"utf8_general_ci", "charset":"utf8", "engine":"MyISAM"})
 */
class Users extends Entity {

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $encrypted_password;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=10)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @Column(type="smallint", options={"default":"0","comment":"0 : Doctor, 1 : Assistant, 2 : Student"}))
     * @var smallint
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=150)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $sef_link;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEncryptedPassword() {
        return $this->encrypted_password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $encrypted_password
     */
    public function setEncryptedPassword($encrypted_password) {
        $this->encrypted_password = $encrypted_password;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt() {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $salt
     */
    public function setSalt($salt) {
        $this->salt = $salt;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getType() {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $type
     */
    public function setType($type) {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSefLink() {
        return $this->sef_link;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $sef_link
     */
    public function setSefLink($sef_link) {
        $this->sef_link = $sef_link;
    }
}
```

UserInformation Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user_information", options={"collate":"utf8_general_ci", "charset":"utf8", "engine":"MyISAM"})
 */
class UserInformation extends Entity {

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $uid;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     * @var date
     */
    protected $born;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", length=65532)
     * @var text
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $cv_path;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $facebook_link;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $twitter_link;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $instagram_link;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $linkedin_link;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $img_path;

    /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     * @var date
     */
    protected $university_graduated_at;

    /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     * @var date
     */
    protected $md_graduated_at;

    /**
     * @Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     * @var date
     */
    protected $associate_professor_graduated_at;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getUid() {
        return $this->uid;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $uid
     */
    public function setUid($uid) {
        $this->uid = $uid;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSurname() {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $surname
     */
    public function setSurname($surname) {
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    /**
     * @return date
     */
    public function getBorn() {
        return $this->born;
    }

    /**
     * @param date $born
     */
    public function setBorn($born) {
        $this->born = $born;
    }

    /**
     * @return text
     */
    public function getAddress() {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * @param text $address
     */
    public function setAddress($address) {
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCvPath() {
        return $this->cv_path;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cv_path
     */
    public function setCvPath($cv_path) {
        $this->cv_path = $cv_path;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFacebookLink() {
        return $this->facebook_link;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $facebook_link
     */
    public function setFacebookLink($facebook_link) {
        $this->facebook_link = $facebook_link;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTwitterLink() {
        return $this->twitter_link;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $twitter_link
     */
    public function setTwitterLink($twitter_link) {
        $this->twitter_link = $twitter_link;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInstagramLink() {
        return $this->instagram_link;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $instagram_link
     */
    public function setInstagramLink($instagram_link) {
        $this->instagram_link = $instagram_link;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinkedinLink() {
        return $this->linkedin_link;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $linkedin_link
     */
    public function setLinkedinLink($linkedin_link) {
        $this->linkedin_link = $linkedin_link;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImgPath() {
        return $this->img_path;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $img_path
     */
    public function setImgPath($img_path) {
        $this->img_path = $img_path;
    }

    /**
     * @return date
     */
    public function getUniversityGraduatedAt() {
        return $this->university_graduated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @param date $university_graduated_at
     */
    public function setUniversityGraduatedAt($university_graduated_at) {
        $this->university_graduated_at = $university_graduated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @return date
     */
    public function getMdGraduatedAt() {
        return $this->md_graduated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @param date $md_graduated_at
     */
    public function setMdGraduatedAt($md_graduated_at) {
        $this->md_graduated_at = $md_graduated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @return date
     */
    public function getAssociateProfessorGraduatedAt() {
        return $this->associate_professor_graduated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @param date $associate_professor_graduated_at
     */
    public function setAssociateProfessorGraduatedAt($associate_professor_graduated_at) {
        $this->associate_professor_graduated_at = $associate_professor_graduated_at;
    }
}
```

Users Service :

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password, $ip, $user_agent) {
        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('App\Entity\Users');
        $user = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')->innerJoin('u.user_information', 'ui')->where('u.email = :email')->setParameter('email', $email);
```

I want to left join one to one users with user_information.

User Information has uid as a unique_key and refer to users id.

How can i left join and get data from user_information where uid = users id?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create relation between your entities.
If you want a oneToOne relation:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserInformation")
     */
    protected $userInformation;
}

class UserInformation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userInformation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $uid;
}
```

Inner join:

```
$user = $repository
  ->createQueryBuilder('u')
  ->addSelect('ui') // to limit queries when doing $user->getUserInformation()
  ->innerJoin('u.userInformation', 'ui')
  ->where('u.email = :email')->setParameter('email', $email);
```

Comment: 'ui WHERE u.email': Error: Class App\Entity\Users has no association named userInformation

Comment: did you had the line `protected $userInformation;` ?